# Filtering records without using a CTE in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a audit table as following:

| TRANSACTION_ID | AUDIT_QUALIFIER | AMOUNT | AUDIT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INIT | 12 | 2023-01-01 |
| 1 | REV | 12 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2 | INIT | 100 | 2023-01-01 |
| 2 | REV | 100 | 2023-01-02 |
| 2 | MOD | 110 | 2023-01-02 |
| 3 | INIT | 1,000 | 2023-01-01 |

I need to output the current state of all the transactions, but not show transactions that have been reversed. The final output should like:

| TRANSACTION_ID | AUDIT_QUALIFIER | AMOUNT | AUDIT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | MOD | 110 | 2023-01-02 |
| 3 | INIT | 1,000 | 2023-01-01 |

I am currently using the following CTE for this:

```
with latest_records as 
(
    select * 
    from transaction_audit
    qualify dense_rank() over (partition by transaction_id order by audit_date desc) = 1
)
select * 
from latest_records 
where audit_qualifier <> 'REV';
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using a CTE?

Comment: why? a CTE is nothing other as a subquery

Comment: Without cte... move the cte to a subquery. Without window functions... that would be interesting.

Comment: Your code is the right way to do this. Rewriting the CTE to a subquery is just syntactical sugar, and would most likely generate the same execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it as

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from transaction_audit
  qualify dense_rank() over (partition by transaction_id order by audit_date desc) = 1
) latest_records 
where audit_qualifier <> 'REV';
```

as you see a CTE is nothing else than a subquery, that can be reused and makes cleaner programming.

SELECT * is a bad habit, better write all the columns that you really need

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your current method works correctly, as I understand it you want to "avoid" the items which have REV record that matches.  To do this you need to self join and then reject those records -- this is the list of "Valid" records that remove the REV

```
SELECT base.transaction_id, MIN(base.trasaction_date) as first_Date
FROM transaction_audit base
LEFT JOIN transaction_audit REV ON base.transaction_id = REV.transaction_id
                               AND REV.audit_qualifier = 'REV' 
                               AND base.amount = REV.amount
                               AND base.audit_date <= REV.audit_date
WHERE base.audit_qualifier <> 'REV'
  AND REV.transaction_id IS NULL
GROUP BY base.transaction_id
```

Once we have the transaction_ids and first dates then we can join that to the table to get the rest of the datea

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction_audit main
JOIN (
  SELECT base.transaction_id, MIN(base.trasaction_date) as first_Date
  FROM transaction_audit base
  LEFT JOIN transaction_audit REV ON base.transaction_id = REV.transaction_id
                                 AND REV.audit_qualifier = 'REV' 
                                 AND base.amount = REV.amount
                                 AND base.audit_date <= REV.audit_date
  WHERE base.audit_qualifier <> 'REV'
    AND REV.transaction_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY base.transaction_id
) sub on SUB.transaction_id = main.transaction_id 
     AND SUB.first_date = main.transaction_date
```